# How can I use TestSuites with Junit4?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this that actually explains how to invoke the testsuite. So far I have this:

```
package gov.hhs.cms.nlr.test;

import java.util.LinkedList;   
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;    
import gov.hhs.cms.nlr.test.marshalling.InquiryMarshallingTest;
import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestSuite; 
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

public class AllTests {

    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses({
        SomeTestTest.class
        SomeOtherTest.class
    })

    public class AllSuites {
        // the class remains completely empty, 
        // being used only as a holder for the above annotations
    }    
}
```

However I do not really understand how I can run this... What I want to do is take all given tests (each test, and from each Class which has Test methods) and put these all into 1 TestSuite and then invoke that.

**Update**: I would like to know how to run this in (**1**) Eclipse and (**2**) hudson and (**3**) plain java/JVM invocation (eg: `java ...`). Thank you.

Comment: Please fix the formatting?  Question: how are you running your tests?  Maven?  Eclipse?  The answer to your question depends quite heavily on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
package gov.hhs.cms.nlr.test;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({OtherTest.class, SomeTestTest.class})
public class AllTests 
{

}
```

Much simpler...  It gives you this:

[image: screenshot of Eclipse running test suite]

### Running in Eclipse

You run it just like a regular JUnit class: Run->Run As->JUnit Test.

### Running in Hudson

Depends how you are running your build. Ant?  Maven?

### Running from Java

Check out the [JUnit FAQ](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_1).  Basically:

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore gov.hhs.cms.nlr.test.AllTests
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way I can see that screenshot from behind something more corporate firewall friendly...? Or perhaps just some annotation would be great, thanks!

Comment: @Zombies: I can email it to you.  It's just a screenshot of what it looks like in Eclipse when you run a suite.

Comment: @the-alchemist: Ah. I see. I think the problem is that Eclipse is not finding the Unit tests (the class which has the suites.) Eclipse is also not finding the TestSuite.

Comment: @Zombies: That's really strange.  It should.  You can also try manually setting up a run configuration through `Run->Run Configurations->JUnit`.  What version of Eclipse do you use?  Every version of Eclipse that supports JUnit 4 recognizes classes with `@RunWith(Suite.class)`.

Comment: @the-alchemist: Helios. I think I had to set the package of the "AllTests" test suite that I was to be creating to the same with the tests in it for them to show. I also needed to rename the tests to start with "test" in the method.

Comment: import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({test1.class,test2.class,test3.class,})
public class   ActiveTestSuite extends TestSuite {
} each of the test*.class has 1 test method, how can i run these test concurrently  ? any help